# Django ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

I have an application `notes` and model name defined as

**notes/models.py**

```
from shorturls.models import ShortUrl

class Note(models.Model):
   # columns here

   def __str___(self):
       return self.title

@receiver(post_save, sender=Note)
def post_save_note_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance and created:
        ShortUrl.objects.create(note=instance)
```

and another app `shorturls` to store short URL for each record with model

**shorturls/models.py**

```
from notes.models import Note

class ShortUrl(models.Model):
    note = models.OneToOneField(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    short_key = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.short_key

@receiver(pre_save, sender=ShortUrl)
def pre_save_short_url_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.short_key = unique_short_key_generator(instance)
```

**But on `python manage.py makemigrations`, It gives error as**

```
File "path_to_app/shorturls/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from notes.models import Note
ImportError: cannot import name 'Note'
```

Comment: updated question and removed that line. That was added by mistake.

Comment: It seems there is circular import because in `Note` i'm importing `ShortUrl` to call `create` of `ShortNote` on `post_save` because I have to create a record for `ShortUrl` everytime a new Note is created.

And In `ShortUrl`, I'm importing `Note` to assign `OneToOneField`.

If this is the cause for circular import, how to get it resolved in this condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between your two models files.

You can use as string in your one-to-one field:

```
class ShortUrl(models.Model):
    note = models.OneToOneField('notes.Note', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

You can then remove `from notes.models import Note` to break the circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Since I'm new to Django and this is my project doing it myself. I would like to ask if this logic I'm implementing is good way or not?

Comment: A circular dependency is often a sign that you haven't structured the code properly. In this case, the simplest way to fix the problem is to use a string in the one-to-one field. Another option would be to move `post_save_note_receiver` into the `shorturls` app. This way, the `shorturls` app would depend on `notes`, but `notes` wouldn't depend on `shorturls`.

Comment: How could I move `post_save_note_receiver` in the `shorturls` as I have to create record for `shorturls` on save of `Note`?

Comment: The code in your question only uses `ShortUrl` in the signal, therefore you should be able to move the signal without any problems.

Comment: I copied the `post_save_receiver` code from `notes/models.py` and pasted in `ShortUrl` with `sender=Note` and removed it from `notes/models.py` and also removed import line and is working fine.
Thanks for the help

Comment: One more help I need on this. How can I access `short_key` of `ShortUrl` using object of `Note`?

Comment: use that query : instance.shorturl.short_key , note.shorturl.short_key

Comment: Perfect answer. That sentence saved my life:
'You have a circular dependency between your two models files.'